# Websocket - "Address already in use"

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, websocket

i used the files contained in this post: http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/. Then i infused them into my codeigniter lab, but i always get an error:

```
Message: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: unable to bind address [48]: Address already in use
```

The JS-part tells me:

```
Connecting...
Connected.
Disconnected.
```

I used the suggested "gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])"-method and also tried the ip without any result.

I guess i have a logical error. Do i need to close the server-side socket first before i can reopen it? I also tried to run the "out-of-the-box"-version (with the correct hostnames), but still no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Live: http://labs.addictivity.de/websockets/

Comment: Which port did you select for the server to listen to? When you run `netstat -anp | grep portnumber`, what output do you see?

Comment: you might have a php process still running the same script, and its listening on that port, preventing other instances of the same script from binding. kill those processes off(just reboot if you dont know how). fyi, you dont want to run the script which acts as the server, through your webserver. run it directly through the php executable(via the command line).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I´m trying to run the script on my webspace so i don´t have much options. I´ll move the whole thing to my server and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Today I cracked the case. My problem was that the server was indeed running with no timeout, but the code was faulty. So I couldn´t set a new one on the same port. Chose another one and voilà. Also got smart enough to set and timeout while testing.